# Applying VLOOKUP for several newline separated lines inside one cell

Tags: excel, vba

In one in my projects I'm in need to apply `VLOOKUP` to several lines of a cell and displaying the output of theses `VLOOKUP`s in another cell.

I'm seeking a function like that:

```
Function LookupNewlineSeparatedItems(lookupRange as Range, cell as Cell)
End Function
```

Assume that `loopupRange` contains something like:

| Ref | Item |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B2 |
| A3 | B3 |
| A4 | B4 |

and cell contains the newline separated lines

| Cell Content (NL separated) |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A3 |
| A5 |

the function should display the result:

| Output |
| --- |
| B1 |
| B3 |
| N/A |

(There is no such thing like A5 in the list, so a special value should displayed.)

I have no experience in VBA Excel up to now. How can I develop a working solution for this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. Are A1, B1, etc all cell references?

Comment: I suspect you might need to explain how the output should be arrived at. What logic was used to get there?

Comment: The items you say are newline separated appear to be single strings with no newlines in them - so there potentially is some detail missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next function (without any iteration):

```
Function LookupNewlineSeparatedItems(lookupRange As Range, cel As Range)
  Dim arrV, arrSpl: arrSpl = Split(cel.value, vbLf)
  With Application
    arrV = .IfError(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(arrSpl, lookupRange, 2, False), "N/A")
    LookupNewlineSeparatedItems = Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(arrV)), vbLf)
  End With
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Debug.Print LookupNewlineSeparatedItems(Range("A2:B5"), ActiveCell)
```

or

```
   ActiveCell.offset(0, 1).value = LookupNewlineSeparatedItems(Range("A2:B5"), ActiveCell)
```

The above code line(s) supposes that in A1:A2 there are headers and `ActiveCell` is the one keeping the new line separated strings (obtained by pressing `Alt + Enter` in cell edit mode).

It also assumes that "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5" are strings and also the content of the `lookupRange`. Your question is not too clear, from this point of view...

Comment: Many thanks for fast solution. I tried it out and it works perfectly for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Column B alignment needs to have wrap text selected.

```vb
Function LookupNewLineSeparatedItems(lookupRange As Range, cell As Range)

   Dim ar, v, i As Long
   ar = Split(cell.Value2, vbLf)
   For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
      v = Application.VLookup(ar(i), lookupRange, 2, 0)
      If IsError(v) Then v = "N/A"
      ar(i) = v
   Next
   LookupNewLineSeparatedItems = Join(ar, vbCrLf)
 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

An additional parameter called column_index added for selecting the column from provided range. This provides slight additional flexibility.

```
Function LookupNewlineSeparatedItems(range As range, column_index As Integer, cell As Variant) As String
 
   Dim values As Variant
      
   'split cell values based on new line character into an array
   
   values = Split(cell, vbNewLine)
         
  'Loop over the array doing a vlookup on each value upon the given range
  
    For i = 0 To UBound(values)
    
       Dim lookup As Variant
       lookup = Application.VLookup(values(i), range, column_index, 0)
       
       'if cell value not found then substitute with "NA"
       
       If Application.IsNA(lookup) Then
         values(i) = "NA"
       Else
        values(i) = lookup
       End If
       
    Next
    
    'use VBA Join function to get final output
    LookupNewlineSeparatedItems = Join(values, vbLf)

End Function
```